# Problem 28 - More square roots- Easy task but I dont know why I am wrong

Tags: java, math

Hello I am solving this task [Problem28](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=28), I think that its a easy task but I dont get the right answer, my answers its 817, the problem asks what is the square root of the sum of the first 10^5 square roots?, I thinks I am correct with my code, but my answers is wrong.

this mis my code, I hope you can help me

```
public class Problema28 {

public static void main(String args[]){
    double sum = 0;
    double number = 0;
    int  j =0;

      for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
        sum = Math.sqrt(j)+sum;
        j++;
        //System.out.println(j);
    }
    number = Math.round(Math.sqrt(sum));
    System.out.println(number);

}
```

}

Comment: Why use `j` when `i` is already generating the same values for you automatically?

Comment: Its just for checking that It turns 100000, but I already get the error thanks, Its a stupid question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `10000` by `100000`.

Answer (score 0):

You are also only checking the first 10^5-1 square roots with your current loop. (After you change the number to 100000 that is)

Comment: It's a `<=` loop, so it'll do `0 ... 100,000`, so it's actually doing 100,001 square roots.